# logging in python

Tags: python

i want to create separate logging file in python like info.log, debug.log, error.log i have a setting file(logging.conf) for logging as given below

```
[loggers]
keys=root,simpleExample

[handlers]
keys=consoleHandler

[formatters]
keys=simpleFormatter

[logger_root]
level=DEBUG
handlers=consoleHandler

[logger_simpleExample]
level=DEBUG
handlers=consoleHandler
qualname=simpleExample
propagate=0

[handler_consoleHandler]
class=StreamHandler
level=DEBUG
formatter=simpleFormatter
args=(sys.stdout,)

[formatter_simpleFormatter]
format=%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s
datefmt=
```

and i have created logging.py file as given below

```
import logging
import logging.config

logging.config.fileConfig('logging.conf')

# create logger
logger = logging.getLogger('simpleExample')

# 'application' code
logger.debug('debug message')
logger.info('info message')
logger.warn('warn message')
logger.error('error message')
logger.critical('critical message')
```

but when execute logging.py file i am getting following result in consol

```
2012-12-10 13:30:20,030 - simpleExample - DEBUG - debug message
2012-12-10 13:30:20,031 - simpleExample - INFO - info message
2012-12-10 13:30:20,032 - simpleExample - WARNING - warn message
2012-12-10 13:30:20,032 - simpleExample - ERROR - error message
2012-12-10 13:30:20,033 - simpleExample - CRITICAL - critical message
```

as i have told i want to create separate file in log.info, debug.info, error.info.
thanks in advance

Comment: That would require a *custom* handler that has both a minimum and a maximum log level. Normally there is only a minimum level (which, internally, are numeric).

Comment: i don not have idea to create custom handler in logging.conf file, can you give any link or reference which will help me.

Comment: It won't be an easy task, I can only point you to the `logging` module documentation really. I'd rethink why you'd want to have separate files in the first place.

Comment: I would find it confusing to have the logging in separate files, myself. When diagnosing a problem I want to know the *exact* order messages were logged, and having the different levels separated would make that a lot more difficult.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to config multiple handler to output different level log to different files. For example, you want to INFO level log to info.log, you can define a fileHandler with INFO filer

```
class MyFilter(logging.Filter):
    def filter(self, rec):
        return rec.levelno == logging.INFO

class MyHandler(logging.FileHandler):
    def __init__(self, *arg, **kw):
        logging.FileHandler.__init__(self, *arg, **kw)
        self.addFilter(MyFilter())
```

And add it to logging namespace:

```
logging.MyHandler = MyHandler
```

so you can use it in your config file:

```
[handlers]
keys=consoleHandler,onlyinfoHandler
[handler_onlyinfoHandler]
class=MyHandler
level=DEBUG
formatter=simpleFormatter
args=('info.log','w')
```

You can continue to add others or use level as handler args.